# How many coins are active in Bcash chain

Tags: bitcoin-cash

How many coins have moved in Bcash chain since the fork? 
Does any web publish a graph tracking this value?

It would be interesting to see how does it compare with an updated version of the chart below ([source](http://www.ofnumbers.com/2014/11/22/approximately-70-of-all-bitcoins-have-not-moved-in-6-or-more-months/)) to check how many old coins were moved to claim BCH apart from the ones split by the exchanges.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

4,636,031 BTC moved on the Bcash side of the fork as of Sept 28th.

4,852,648 BTC moved on the Bitcoin side of the fork as of Sept 28th.

Source: some scripts I run regularly. I intend to create a website with it at some point.